# how to space multiple lines in github issues

Tags: ruby, github, formatting, keyboard-shortcuts

I am copying a bunch of log output to a github issue and I want to indent it so that it is distinguishable as code/output from the rest of the issue.

How do I do this?

I tried:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

but none seem to work? I really don't want to do every single line individually..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside  ```` ``` ````.

You can also specify language name after  if your log file is analogus to any programming language's syntax.
e.g. 
    ```` ```yaml ````

You can refer [Gihub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) for more info.

Comment: how can I do multiple lines though? If i put it at the beggining and then at the end the line breaks are lost....

Comment: There should be able to do multiple lines stylized without loosing the line breaks... Is there a shortcut for adding the tick marks to multiple highlighted rows all at once?